# How to serve a file read with fs.readFile

Tags: node.js, file, download

i'm developing an application with nodejs. I have to read a local file on server, i'm using this function:

```
fs.readFile(path, "utf8", function (err,data) {}
```

how i can serve the 'data' to client? is good to open it in a new tab or downloading it on client.

--UPDATE--
I'm trying to use this solution, too.. is a good way?

```
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/pdf"});
res.write(data);
res.end();
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using some sort of HTTP server here, you'll receive a `response` object in the handler.  This object is actually a stream.  I'm using the built-in node HTTP server here for my example.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
});
```

In [express](http://expressjs.com) and [hapi](http://hapijs.com) there is a specific send-file response type if you're using those:

Hapi: [reply.file](http://hapijs.com/api#replyfilepath-options)

Express: [res.sendFile](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile)

Comment: fs = require('fs'); var path = "W:\\xxxx" ;
fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);   is correct in this way?